# writing LZW program in matlab

Tags: matlab

i'm writing LZW in matlab,but i don't know how i should make dictionary?
i want some help in writing program.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a `containers.Map` class available in newer verisons of MATLAB.

```
help containers.Map
```

should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

if you can be guaranteed that the keys are alphanumeric, starting with a char, I would just use a struct to do the lookups. struct field -> value lookups are reasonably fast. if the keys are integers, I would use a sparse array to point to indices in a cell, but that will require more overhead.